# Upload File to Server in PHP Error

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, upload, hosting

I am uploading a file to server using HTML form and creating a TXT file in server to write error logs but This process running well in my locaal system and in my other server but not in   One Server where this operation has to work.

The error message:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(taskfinished/512557562_348011_RAND_488.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/smart_1/JSON/taskimageupload.php on line 70 

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpz3HWEJ' to 'taskfinished/512557562_348011_RAND_488.png' in /var/www/smart_1/JSON/taskimageupload.php on line 70 

Warning: fopen(errorlog/07.30.13.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/smart_1/JSON/errorlog.php on line 30 

Warning: fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/smart_1/JSON/errorlog.php on line 35 

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/smart_1/JSON/errorlog.php on line 37
```

I turned off SAFE MODE but still the issue is same..

How can I change the user permission in my server.?

My PHP  CODE:

```
$finenamedynamic = $CompanyId."_".$ShibNo."_RAND_".rand(100,600);
    //$finenamedynamic = date("Y-m-d-H_i_s")."_RAND_".rand(100,600);
    //New file name with EXTENSION
    $newfilename=$finenamedynamic.".".$extension;
    // Upload file
    $uploadedimage = $targetfilename . $newfilename;
    //Move file to the new file path
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadedimage)){
        //Error Log
        $message = "Error uploading file - check destination is writeable ". $uploadedimage;
        ErrorsAreAwesome('70','taskimageupload.php','Create Directory',$message);
    }

function ErrorsAreAwesome($line=null,$filename=null,$function=null,$message=null){
    //Create Error file for the day
    $myFile = "errorlog/".date("m.d.y").".txt";
    $error_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //Construct Error
    $file_write = "[".$error_time."]-->[Line:".$line."]-->[File:".$filename."]-->[Fun:".$function."]-->[Msg:".$message."]";

    //if file exist appen in the file else create new file and write
    if (file_exists($myFile)) {
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
    } else {
      $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    } 
    //write in file \r\n support for this OS or \n alone work
    fwrite($fh, "\r\n".$file_write."\n");
    //close file after writing
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Comment: show us the code you use. for linux server you can use chmod to change permission.

Comment: it is not a perrmision. problem are you sure that folder exists or the path correct. cos sometimes you have to give full path like /var/www/smart_1/folder

Comment: yes the folder and path exist thats why its working well in my other servers as well in my local..

Comment: I have added my code now.. @Aris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by the following means:

Find your `php.ini` file in server in my case it is in `usr/Apache/bin`

and find out the below code:

```
; Safe Mode
; http://php.net/safe-mode
safe_mode = On
```

change the above code to below

```
; Safe Mode
; http://php.net/safe-mode
safe_mode = Off
```

Then Change the `File Permission..`

Change Mode 0777 to the below folders:

```
taskfinished
errorlog
```

That's the issue resolved!

Hope this help some one!

Answer (score 0):

if you run thous test cases, what error message do you get?

```
if(!is_dir('taskfinished'))
{
   die("1: dir taskfinished dosn't exists\n");
}

if(!is_writable('taskfinished'))
{
   die("2: dir taskfinished isn't writeable\n");
}

$file_resource = fopen('taskfinished/test.txt', 'w');
if(!$file_resource)
{
   die("3: failed to open file\n");
}

if(!fwrite($file_resource, 'test'))
{
   fclose($file_resource);
   die("4: Failed to write to file\n");
}

fclose($file_resource);
die("All test passed\n");
```

for 1 you need to create the folder `mkdir taskfinished`
for 2 you need to change the owner or permission of the folder `chown apache:apache taskfinished` (CHangeOWNer to user apache and group apache) or `chmod o+w` (CHange MODe for Owner add Write)
for 3 or 4 I have no clue